# Termes d'adresse (tu ou vous) dans une application mobile de motivation

Tags: informatique, vouvoiement, tutoiement

La question / le problème : dans une application mobile dédiée à la motivation à l'activité physique, qui envoie des messages motivationnels aux utilisateurs, est-il préférable d'employer le vouvoiement ou le tutoiement dans les messages ?

Exemple de tutoiement : Ta santé est en jeu, ne l’oublie pas !
Exemple de vouvoiement : Votre santé est en jeu, ne l'oubliez pas !

Le contexte : je suis doctorant en informatique, et j'ai développé l'application mobile mentionnée ci-dessus. Les rapporteurs de ma thèse ont relevé l'emploi du tutoiement, en me demandant de préciser s'il existe des publications, ou des instructions "officielles" quant à l'emploi du tutoiement ou du vouvoiement dans ce type de contexte. Je précise être français natif.

J'ai cherché sur Google Scholar avec les termes : tutoyer, vouvoyer et variations associées, appli* mobile, sans rien trouver de pertinent (rien en rapport avec une application mobile). *Idem* sur juste Google, et *idem* ici sur FrenchSE.

Je me demande si FrenchSE comprend dans ses membres des experts qui puissent m'éclairer ou m'orienter sur cette question. Je préfèrerai avoir une référence bibliographique que je pourrai utiliser lors de ma soutenance, par exemple une notice d'information du CNRTL ou du site du Dictionnaire de l'Académie.

Les arguments pour ou contre l'un ou l'autre sont souvent les mêmes, sans pour autant citer de sources précises : proximité, simplicité, légèreté, informalité pour le tutoiement, respect, politesse, formalité pour le vouvoiement. Concernant le sujet spécifique des messages motivationnels par un programme informatique, je n'ai rien trouvé.

S'agissant d'une application mobile (donc sur un téléphone personnel) dédiée à la motivation à la marche à pied (donc plutôt une activité de loisir que professionnelle) par des messages adressés directement à l'utilisateur de l'application (comme dans une conversation), ne sommes-nous pas ainsi dans un cadre plus informel que formel ? Le tutoiement pourrait-il être plus naturel dans ce cas ?

Comment: à ce stade, l'application n'est plus modifiable avant un moment, puisque je soutiens dans deux semaines. la question n'est d'ailleurs pas de savoir ce que je peux faire dans l'application, mais quelle est la règle, ou la pratique à suivre dans ce genre de cas, si elle existe. je suis également OK si la réponse est "il n'y a pas de règles", ou "il faut vouvoyer", du moment qu'une source "officielle" (bibliographique) existe pour l'attester.

Comment: C'est un peu bizarre - tu crois vraiment qu'il y aurait une "règle" à laquelle tous les vendeurs de logiciels adhéreraient forcément, juste parce que c'est "la règle"? Je ne crois pas que le domaine soit aussi prescriptif, il faut pouvoir atteindre différents segments de la population en maximisant l'engagement, et pouvoir se différencier aussi sur le plan marketing. Tu peux peut-être switcher entre le tu et le vous dès que l'utilisateur a entré son âge dans l'appli?

Comment: Moi qui ne fais pas partie des djeuns depuis de lustres j'ai le tutoiement très facile dans certains contextes le premier étant que mon interlocuteur sache qu'il s'adresse à moi et vice versa. Je considère qu'une appli qui tutoierait la personne inconnue de l'autre côté de l'écran s'adresse à des enfants et que donc elle n'est pas pour moi.

Comment: @Frank je ne suis pas un vendeur de logiciel, je suis un chercheur avant tout : d'ailleurs, mes travaux seront publiés en open source après la soutenance. le marketing ne m'intéresse pas, j'essaie ici de proposer une application de recherche qui suive les pratiques de communication entre êtres humains les plus justes possibles. relativement aux applications mobiles de motivation en langue française, le manque de sources et de règles claires est évident, ce que la réponse de ninja étoilé met en avant.

Comment: @V4karian Le marketing n'est qu'un angle. Considère le commentaire de None, qui fait écho à ce que je disais sur l'âge: si ton appli tutoies ou vouvoies, tu risques de perdre soit les plus de 30 ans, soit les moins de 30 ans... (en très gros, "30 ans" arbitraire juste pour l'argument). Difficile d'ignorer qui est le public que tu cibles à mon avis.

Comment: @Frank le public cible, c'est 18+. Dans la 1ère version, nous avions le vouvoiement, et sur suggestion de mon directeur de thèse, nous sommes passés au tutoiement. la question n'a jamais été ni débattue, ni argumentée, mais je dois quand même l'adresser dans ma soutenance. notre discussion ici alimente ma réflexion, et ma réponse / présentation sur ce sujet, merci !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On connaît déjà les [contextes](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/25140/la-redaction-et-la-communication/protocole-et-activites-publiques/contextes-demploi-du-vouvoiement-et-du-tutoiement) du vouvoiement (formel etc.) et ceux en faveur tu tutoiement (proximité etc.). On sait que l'âge, le genre, la profession et la zone géographique sont des [facteurs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutoiement_et_vouvoiement_en_fran%C3%A7ais). Ici en résumé on a des messages d'encouragement et le contexte est ludique. Mais le public cible est-il du même âge. Difficile de trancher ; une application a une vocation universelle. On a le choix et aucun choix n'est « parfait », d'où que de [s'adapter](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54314/termes-dadresse-tu-ou-vous-dans-une-application-mobile-de-motivation#comment116819_54314) à l'âge ou d'offrir l'option tutoiement/vouvoiement dans les paramètres de l'application pourrait être utile.

Dans l'univers des services sur le web, on a des exemples de cas. *Debitoor* avait choisi le tutoiement et devant les réactions ils se sont [expliqués](https://debitoor.fr/blog/pourquoi-utilisons-nous-le-tutoiement) ; suite à leur changement de nom ils semblent être [revenus](https://www.sumup.com/fr-fr/factures/) au vouvoiement. [Ailleurs](https://www.24joursdeweb.fr/2018/importance-du-wording-dans-les-interfaces-d-aujourdhui/), on se pose des questions, parfois on peut formuler différemment et éviter d'avoir à faire un choix ou présenter un double formulation et j'ai noté par exemple « Félicitations, ton/votre compte a bien été créé ». Il y a d'autres nuances, on donne un exemple « modifier mes informations » et non pas « modifier vos informations » ; donc on peut avoir des nuances avec les adjectifs possessifs aussi et l'angle selon lequel c'est présenté (utilisateur vs. application). [Ailleurs](https://fr.deezercommunity.com/tu-n-as-pas-trouve-le-bon-sujet-14/tutoiement-insupportable-38471) encore, le passage du vouvoiement au tutoiement en cours de vie de l'application en a fait réagir certains, malgré les meilleures intentions (« pour refléter au mieux la relation que nous avons avec les utilisateurs »). Il faut compiler un grand nombre de cas du genre et les étudier.

On peut réfléchir mais à mon avis il était un peu présomptueux de penser que des règles formelles ont été conçues pour les applications mobiles différemment de tout autre contexte, a fortiori pour des messages motivationnels dans un logiciel un peu ludique d'une telle application, tout comme il était peu pragmatique il me semble de concevoir la situation comme nécessitant de trancher par le tutoiement ou le vouvoiement exclusivement. Répondre au désir particulier de la personne qui utilise l'application est à mon avis la meilleure solution.

Comment: Magnifique réponse !! Grâce à T·V·o·i·us il y aura bientôt un Phd provençal de plus et une amélioration définitive au programme.

Comment: Merci de ta réponse. L'évolution de la langue implique de voir apparaître de nouvelles règles, au fur et à mesure que de nouveaux usages deviennent communs. Les réformes menées sur l'orthographe, en autres choses, en sont la preuve. Concernant mon sujet, la réponse est "il n'existe pas (encore) de règles, ça dépend du contexte, on préférera le vouvoiement et laisser le choix à l'utilisateur", et je m'en contente, c'est précisément ce que je demandais.

Comment: @V4karian Oui, la langue évolue, absolument, et c'est à cette évolution d'un usage que convie une analyse de cas dans le domaine, mais les convenances demeurent aussi, peut-être encore davantage en France qu'au Québec puis qu'aux É.-U., et l'analyse reste fondamentalement la même peu importe que ce soit un service ou une application. Les règles existent déjà, mais la difficulté est entre autre de définir la relation entre l'application et l'utilisateur, est-ce la même chose qu'entre un agent d'une société et un client etc. Parfois par exemple on commence avec le vous puis on passe au tu etc.

Comment: @Personne Merci, peut-être que ça peut faire le chemin inverse et qu'on pourra demander aux gens leur préférence dans un contexte en personne etc. sans rester à cheval sur les convenances juste pour la forme. L'avenir le dira. Bien à vous !

Answer (score 0):

À mon avis la question que l'on doit se poser est «jusqu'à quel point ai-je envie d'imiter le style anglosaxon ?». Je m'explique : il y a tout un imaginaire autour de la Californie, de la Silicon Valley, et… de la motivation à l'activité physique qui, aux États-Unis, est bien plus ancrée dans les mœurs qu'ici. Mon argument est que la motivation à l'activité physique est une activité qui reflète bien les valeurs, ou du moins l'imaginaire américain pour ne pas dire, californien.

Bien évidemment les anglophones n'ont pas de distinction entre le tu et le vous (le *thou* ne se manifestant que dans des citations bibliques), du coup ils ne comprennent pas bien la différence et se trompent souvent quand ils s'expriment dans des langues étrangères ou quand ils traduisent des interfaces utilisateur dans d'autres langues. En même temps ils ont l'habitude de s'appeler mutuellement par leurs prénoms, ce qui nous incité à traduire leurs *you* par des tu. Sans parler de la tradition infiniment juteuse des traducteurs de dialogues de films anglosaxons de passer au tutoiement dès qu'une relation a été consommée, avec les sempiternelles mêmes étapes : le couple qui jusqu'alors se vouvoyait se jette sur le lit, la caméra se déplace vers l'abat-jour, fondu noir, il est jour, ils se réveillent, ils se tutoient…

Tout cela pour dire que votre décision d'utiliser le tu ou le vous dépendra entre autres aussi de votre positionnement vis-à-vis de l'influence culturelle américaine qui, en matière de motivation à l'activité physique, n'est pas négligeable. Et cela doit être conforme à l'esprit de l'application, à son design graphique, à la rhétorique qu'elle véhicule, à sa philosophie.

D'autres pays européens ont le même problème, et je vois de plus en plus souvent dans les sites Web/applis allemands et grecs le passage au tu, je vois des interfaces utilisateur qui reprennent à merveille leurs pendants américains.

Pour finir, la question n'est pas linguistique mais sociolinguistique (à quelle population s'adresse-t-on ?) et psycholinguistique (quel est le but recherché au niveau du récepteur du message ?). Imaginez ceux·elles qui utiliseront votre application, comment se positionnent il·elle·s vis-à-vis de la modernité et du fitness américain ? S'il·elle·s y adhèrent, alors le tutoiement sera tout à fait compatible avec leurs attentes. Si non, et si la motivation à l'activité physique n'a rien à voir avec le modèle américain de la relation avec son corps, alors il vaut mieux rester dans le cadre des conventions françaises et vouvoyer quelqu'un qu'on ne connaît pas.

Comment: je ne comprends pas bien le rapport entre la motivation à l'activité physique et la culture "américaine" (étasunienne ?). l'activité physique est un moyen de prévention des maladies chroniques, cela est attesté par la HAS, l'INSERM, l'ANSES, rien à voir avec les États-Unis. il est question de santé publique ici, et de comment faire en sorte que plus de personnes soient motivées à bouger davantage.
du reste, j'ai bien précisé dans ma question que c'est la formulation qui m'intéresse, ainsi qu'avoir des sources bibliographiques et/ou officielles, que je puisse utiliser dans ma soutenance.

Comment: @V4karian Une autre solution serait d'éviter le problème en utilisant des tournures qui ne nécessitent ni le _tu_, ni le _vous_, si cela est possible: _Pour rester en bonne santé, l'exercice est primordial!_ par exemple.

Comment: @TheExploptimist Une application qui m'incite à faire de l'exercice physique est pour moi un cas typique d'application «à l'américaine». Ce n'est pas l'activité physique en soi, mais l'incitation à la pratiquer à travers une appli mobile, c'est cela qui est typiquement américain. N'avez-vous pas vu les pubs de l'iWatch ?

Comment: @yannis je suis sur Android (l'appli aussi), et je ne regarde pas de pubs (pas de TV, et bloqueur de pub sur internet), donc non, je n'ai pas vu. encore une fois, je suis chercheur, j'ai un point de vue de recherche, pour faire avancer la science, pas vendre un produit. la recherche n'a pas de frontière, la science non plus, puisque les travaux des uns sont basés sur les résultats des autres. quant à la motivation à pratiquer par une appli, c'est juste dans l'ère du temps : les mobiles sont très répandus, au point qu'ils sont le premier appareil d'accès à internet en France (Arcep 2023).

Comment: @TheExploptimist *L'ère du temps* est une expression singulière. Tu voulais sûrement dire *l'air du temps* :-)

Comment: @jlliagre tout à fait, merci de la correction. Hélas, je ne peux éditer mon commentaire pour le corriger :/